# Dynamic layout: how to get specific view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity in which I need to add LinearLayout dynamically, by code (because it depends on the user input).
So, here is what I have done:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout lyt = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_edit, mLytRows);
TextView tvName = (TextView) lyt.findViewById(R.id.name_textview);
tvName.setText(user.getName());
```

where `R.layout.row_edit` is a LinearLayout in which there are some Views, including a TextView, whereas `mLytRows` is a referenced LinearLayout (defined in the XML of the UI), in which I want to add the `row_edit` layout.

Based on the user input, I repeat this code several times and here is the problem:
when I try to reference the TextView, I aways get the TextView of the first LinearLayout I have added.

Why? How can I solve it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29).

If you specify the second argument in `inflate()`, the method returns the parent, not the inflated View.

Hence, `lyt` is always your parent and `findViewById` always returns the first element it finds with the `R.id.name_textview` ID.

You might want to do

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout lyt = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_edit, null);
TextView tvName = (TextView) lyt.findViewById(R.id.name_textview);
tvName.setText(user.getName());
mLytRows.addView(lyt);
```

And in [ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) you can see there are several `addView` methods to place the view where you want.

Comment: aaahhh!! Thank you! Now I also understand why I casted lyt to LinearLayout instead of FrameLayout that is the layout type of row_edit... thank you indeed!

Answer (score 0):

In your res/layout/my_image_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    ...>
    <ImageView ...
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

To grab that Layout by its @+id value inside your app/src/java/MyClass.java code, do this:

```
    String myLinearLayoutName = "buttons";
    LinearLayout myLinearLayoutID2 = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(activity.getResources()
            .getIdentifier(myLinearLayoutName, "id", activity.getPackageName()));

    /*Bottom code changes that LinearLayout's background to a different image. "bomb" (R.mipmap.bomb) is the name of an image I have in my drawable folder. */
    myLinearLayoutID2.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.bomb);
```